# Nuxt3 @nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript package error: Cannot find module 'typescript'

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, eslint

```json
// package.json

{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^12.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.50.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.17.0",
    "nuxt": "^3.7.3"
  }
}
```

```js
// .eslintrc.cjs

module.exports = {
    root: true,
    env: {
        browser: true,
        es2021: true,
        node: true
    },
    parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
    parserOptions: {
        parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
        sourceType: "module",
    },
    plugins: [
        'vue',
        '@typescript-eslint'
    ],
    extends: [
        'plugin:nuxt/recommended',
        'airbnb-base',
        'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended',
        '@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript'
    ],
}
```

```js
// nuxt.config.ts

// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: [
    ['@nuxtjs/eslint-module', { /* module options */ }],
  ],
})
```

These are the configuration files I wrote.

when i run this project, throw error like this

`Cannot start nuxt:  Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in '.eslintrc.cjs » @nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript': Cannot find module 'typescript'`

Installing typescript solves the problem, but I don't think you should do this since nuxt has a built-in typescript package by default.

Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: If you're using VSCode, try opening the Command Palette (Ctrl-Shift-P) and entering 'Select Typescript Version'. Choose the workspaces version, see if that helps.

Comment: It still doesn't work...

Comment: `npm install -D typescript`

Comment: I could just do a clean install of typescript, but shouldn't I be using nuxt built-in typescript? 
Isn't this a double installation of typescript?